# Redirect domains with lighttpd?

Tags: lighttpd, redirection

I'm working on getting a Wordpress MU install running on my VPS. I enabled the 'simple-vhost' mod and can access the site fine.

The problem is I can only get to it from domain.com. If I try www.domain.com I get shown the lighthttpd page? I'd like to get everything pointing to one place.

My DNS records look like this:

```
*.domain.ORG xx.xx.xx domain.ORG 300 A 
domain.ORG xx.xx.xx domain.ORG 300 A 
WWW.domain.ORG domain.ORG domain.ORG 300 CNAME 
domain.ORG domain.ORG domain.ORG 300 MX
```

What is happening?

Thanks

Edit:
lighttpd.conf here:

http://pastebin.com/A1auSn6R

Comment: posting your lighttpd.conf would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS config seems fine - however the www.domain.org is superfluous as *.domain.org already does the same thing.

You need to configure your existing virtual host for `www.domain.com` to respond to requests for `domain.com`. If you want it to respond to requests to `*.domain.com`, you'll need to edit the virtual host file (located under `/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled` on Debian) to something like that :

```
$HTTP["host"] == "(^|.*\.|\.)domain\.com$" {
   server.document-root = "/var/www"
}
```